# How to set two images on 4 different image views?

Tags: ios, ios4

I have 2 images and i have 4 iamges view i want to set that 2 images on 2-2 imageview randomly.

Just like card game.In that user select 1 card then user have 3 more option for open the same image if image is same then user win the game after another click. help me please...

```
int r =arc4random()%4;
int z=arc4random()%4;
UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:r];
imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"30-by-30-home"];

if(r!=z)
{
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:z];
    imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"30-by-30-home"];

}else{

     if(r==3)
     {
         UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:z-2];
         imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"30-by-30-home"];
     }
    if(r==0)
    {
        UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:z+2];
        imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"30-by-30-home"];


    }if(r==1)
    {
        UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:z+2];
        imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"30-by-30-home"];
    }
    if(r==2)
    {
        UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:z-2];
        imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"30-by-30-home"];
    }

}
```

Comment: make sure the tags are different

Comment: what is represented by "z"?

Comment: int z=arc4random()%4;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

arc4random() is the name of the function which generates random number.

Use it like arc4random()%3 to generate the random number. Based on the random number select the image.

You should generate two different random numbers.

```
int r =arc4random()%4;
int z=arc4random()%4;

 while (r==z)
 {
      z = arc4random()%4;
      if(r != z)
         break;
 }

UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:r];
imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"30-by-30-home"];

UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:z];
imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"30-by-30-home"];
```

Comment: yes i did it but i get succes to set 1 image on 2 imageview but i didnt get success to set another image on rest image views

Answer (score 0):

For both `r==3` & `r==2` you use `[self.view viewWithTag:z-2]`.

And for both `r==0` & `r==1` you use `[self.view viewWithTag:z+2]`.

Might that be the cause of it?

Comment: do you have any example for that?just like card matching game in 2*2 matrix.